# Executing Stored procedure with Codeigniter 2 & Oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, codeigniter-2

Its been an hour I m having trouble executing oracle stored procedures in Codeigniter 2. I m not being able to find proper documentation for CI+Stored procedures.

**My Stored Procedure :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE SP_DISTRICT_INSERT(P_DST_NAME VARCHAR2, FLAG VARCHAR2 Default '0',P_USER_ID Number) AS

PKEY NUMBER:=0;

         BEGIN

             SELECT MAX(NVL(DST_ID,0))+1 INTO PKEY FROM DISTRICT ;

      INSERT INTO DISTRICT(DST_ID, DST_NAME, USER_ID, ENTERED_DATE, FLAG) VALUES(PKEY,P_DST_NAME,P_USER_ID,SYSDATE ,FLAG);

     COMMIT ;



EXCEPTION

        WHEN OTHERS THEN

 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,PKEY|| 'INVALID_NO'|| P_DST_NAME|| 'DATAMISMATCH'|| SQLERRM, TRUE) ;

END SP_DISTRICT_INSERT ;
```

**AND I executed stored procedure in my model like this**

```
$ins=$this->db->query("call SP_DISTRICT_INSERT('abcdxyz',1,1)");
```

**The page showing error**

```
Error Number:

call SP_DISTRICT_INSERT('abcdxyz',1,1)

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\..\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

**However,**

If i call procedure directly from Navicat, it works

Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.** I m using Codeigniter 2  and Oracle 11g

Thanks

Comment: Please read up on [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CNCPT611) and the judicious use of whitespace. I've never used Codeignitor, however, you're not quoting your second variable and I suspect the `call` in there is wrong.

Comment: That didnt work either. Yes its correct to use `call` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was database field length. The scenario is that after form submission, the input string is converted into unicode format like `&#129;`. So if database field length is 10 and i input string with 4 characters, the procedure returned error because 4 characters when converted into unicode format becomes around 24 characters which is bigger than the allowed length in database field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rsponse = '';
    $s = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, "begin packageName.procedureName(:bind1,:bind2,:bind3,:bind4,:bind5); end;");
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind1", $data['fieldOne'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind2", $data['fieldTwo'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind3", $data['fieldThre'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind4", $data['fieldFour'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind4", $response,300);
               oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT); 
echo $message; // returned value
```

n the above example procedure accept four arguments as input and one parameter as output. in case of direct calling procedure remove 'packageName.' That's it...